# Calculate time per day, but with parameters with two days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, calculation

I am working on the calculation of time.

Here an example: I have time of open session and session off

[image]

I want to calculate a time of connection but per day. The problem here is that the disconnect time is the next day.
(on the picture) For the first line time connexion for the 2017-01-19 will be from 7:49 am to midnight.
Time connexion for the 2017-01-20 will be **from midinight to 00:39am** and **8:48am to midinight**.
I don't know how to retrieve the time from the previous day.

I started to do something like that but I'm not satisfied :

```
Sessionid   sessionOn               SessionOff              Time(hour)     Time+1
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------  -------
1           2017-01-19 07:49:42.600 2017-01-20 00:39:31.247 16           0.39
2           2017-01-20 07:56:01.030 2017-01-21 00:36:36.863 16           0.36
```

Then the Time+1 will be added to the time for the next day (with a transaction maybe).  I am using SQL server.

Do you know how can I do that in a cleaner way?

Expected Result

```
Sessionid   Time of connexion (hour)               
----------- -------
1           16h11           
2           16h43
```

Comment: "Time connexion for the 2017-01-20 will be from midinight to 00:39am and 8:48am to midinight" So, Will there be two records for '2017-01-20'. I think you should reorganize your table before select this report.

Comment: So basically a connection can have time for more than one day?
For example in this case: Sessionid 1 has time on 1/19 as 7:49 till midnight
and then on 1/20 Sessionid 1 will have time as 39 minutes. Am I right?

Comment: We can only have 1 days between Session on and sessionoff.
Yes you are right !

Comment: @maitiko: It would be easy for us to answer if you can include expected results in your question for the same example.

Comment: okay ! I will do it

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
declare @x table(sessionOn datetime, sessionOff datetime)
insert into @x values
('2017-01-19 07:49:42.600','2017-01-20 00:39:31.247'),
('2017-01-20 07:56:01.030','2017-01-21 00:36:36.093'),
('2017-01-23 08:10:03.937','2017-01-24 00:47:10.893')

select C1, floor(C2/3600) [hour], floor(C2 % 3600 / 60) [minute], FLOOR(C2 % 60) [second] from (
select ISNULL(A.DayOfSession, B.DayOfSession) [C1],
       ISNULL(A.DurationInSec, 0) + ISNULL(B.DurationInSec, 0) [C2]
from 
    (select cast(sessionOn as date) as DayOfSession, DATEDIFF(second, sessionOn, cast(sessionOff as date)) DurationInSec from @x) as A
full join
    (select cast(sessionOff as date) as DayOfSession, DATEDIFF(second, cast(sessionOff as date), sessionOff) DurationInSec from @x) as B
on A.DayOfSession = B.DayOfSession
) as a
```

Here's little explanation:

first subquery calculates duration from `SessionOn` until midnight (in seconds);

second query calculates duration from midnight until `SessionOff`.

This durations are calculated in different subqueries and have assigned to them correct date (without time).

Now, there's simple join based on date :)

Here's result set:

[image]

**REGARDING OP'S COMMENT TO THIS POST**

One way is to change subqueries:

first one:

```
(select cast(sessionOn as date) as DayOfSession, 
        case when Datepart(day,SessionOn) = Datepart(day,SessionOff) then
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, sessionOn, sessionOff) else
            DATEDIFF(second, sessionOn, cast(sessionOff as date))
        end DurationInSec 
from @x)
```

second query:

```
(select cast(sessionOff as date) as DayOfSession, 
        case when Datepart(day,SessionOn) = Datepart(day,SessionOff) then 0 else
            DATEDIFF(second, cast(sessionOff as date), sessionOff)
        end DurationInSec 
from @x)
```

Comment: thanks I 'm going to try this right now ! 
But I forgot to say that I have some 'Sessionoff' that are on the same date.
Can I include a condition here ?
(for example (if date(sessionOn) < date(sessionOff)) then do this transaction ?